# ConfigMap is not working well with application.properties but works well with application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube, application.properties, configmap

New to k8s.

Went through https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/2.1.0.RC1/multi/multi__kubernetes_propertysource_implementations.html

I am having multi profiles in config map and want my app to pickup the properties based on the spring.profiles.active.

**Case 1:-**

My ConfigMap looks like,

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-configmap-overriding-new-02
data:
  application.properties: |-
    globalkey = global key value
    TeamName = Team Name value
    Purpose = Purpose value
    RootFile = Root file value
    Company = company value
    Place = Place value
    Country = Country value
    ---
    spring.profiles = qa
    globalkey = global key qa value
    TeamName = Team Name qa value
    Purpose = Purpose qa value
    RootFile = Root file qa value
    ---
    spring.profiles = prod
    globalkey = global key prod value
    Company = company prod value
    Place = Place prod value
    Country = Country prod value
```

My deployment file looks like,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: demo-configmapsingleprofile
spec:  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo-configmapsingleprofile
  replicas: 1
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo-configmapsingleprofile
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: config-reader
      containers:
      - name: demo-configmapsingleprofile
        image: image name
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: example-configmap-overriding-new-02
        securityContext:
            privileged: false
```

My Config file in spring boot looks like,

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigConsumerConfig {

@Value(value = "${globalkey}")
private String globalkey;

@Value(value = "${TeamName}")
private String teamName;

@Value(value = "${Purpose}")
private String purpose;

@Value("${RootFile}")
private String rootFile;

@Value("${Company}")
private String company;

@Value("${Place}")
private String place;

@Value("${Country}")
private String country;

//With getters and setters
}
```

My application.properties looks like,

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
spring.application.name=example-configmap-overriding-new-02
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.name=example-configmap-overriding-new-02
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.namespace=default
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.sources[0].name=example-configmap-overriding-new-02
spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enabled=true
```

**App is starting fine and it grabbed the values from the config map. But it is picking from wrong profile. Some values are picked up from qa profile.**

I am getting the final result as:-

```
{"globalkey":"global key prod value","teamName":"Team Name qa value","purpose":"Purpose qa value","rootFile":"Root file qa value","company":"company prod value","place":"Place prod value","country":"Country prod value"}
```

**Case 2:-**

But, when I used the config map with yaml, as given below,

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-configmap-overriding-new-02
data:
  application.yml: |-    
    globalkey : global key value
    TeamName : Team Name value
    Purpose : Purpose value
    RootFile : Root file value
    Company : company value
    Place : Place value
    Country : Country value
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: qa
    globalkey : global key qa value
    TeamName : Team Name qa value
    Purpose : Purpose qa value
    RootFile : Root file qa value
    ---
    spring:
      profiles: prod
    globalkey : global key prod value
    Company : company prod value
    Place : Place prod value
    Country : Country prod value
```

**I am getting the result as expected. It picks from prod profile as expected.**

```
{"globalkey":"global key prod value","teamName":"Team Name value","purpose":"Purpose value","rootFile":"Root file value","company":"company prod value","place":"Place prod value","country":"Country prod value"}
```

**Case 2 is working as expected but not the Case 1.**

Am I doing any mistake/misunderstanding with config map. Could some one advice here?

Thx.

Comment: I don't think that is valid properties format. You cannot split profiles in the properties format. Though, the top of the documentation sounds like you might be able to name each key in the `ConfigMap` like `application-prod.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are no other answers yet...let me try to help you.

The `---` divider in a YAML file separates multiple YAML documents. Not so in a properties file. Not sure how the properties file gets loaded at all with those `---` but otherwise the way it is structured right now it leads to duplicate keys where a key overwrites the same key before it.

Create multiple key/value pairs - one for each profile - when using properties files. Something like this:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-configmap-overriding-new-02
data:
  application.properties: |-
    globalkey = global key value
    TeamName = Team Name value
    Purpose = Purpose value
    RootFile = Root file value
    Company = company value
    Place = Place value
    Country = Country value
  application-qa.properties: |-
    spring.profiles = qa
    globalkey = global key qa value
    TeamName = Team Name qa value
    Purpose = Purpose qa value
    RootFile = Root file qa value
  application-prod.properties: |-
    spring.profiles = prod
    globalkey = global key prod value
    Company = company prod value
    Place = Place prod value
    Country = Country prod value
```

They will "materialize" inside a running container as individual files at the mounted location.

Comment: Hi @apisim: Thx for the reply. Yes. I tried the config file which suggested already. Even though, I specified the active profile to "prod", app is picking up all values from the application.properties. Any idea, why it is not respecting the application-prod.properties? Is this by design or am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: @NANDAKUMAR - if using properties and not yaml file format is important, I'd suggest to mount the ConfigMap as a volume (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#populate-a-volume-with-data-stored-in-a-configmap) and have Spring Cloud Kubernetes read the files from the file system by configuring `spring.cloud.kubernetes.config.paths`; I'd also remove `...envFrom.configMapRef` from the Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/commit/296bf1e351c24107c308422f8e5f24c0cdde1eba)

> Another option is to create a different config map per profile and spring boot will automatically fetch it based on active profiles

You can also consider these approach:

```
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
          name: example-configmap-overriding-new-02
          key: application-prod.properties
```